# changing an images src value when the user scrolls jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to attach an event handler to the scroll event that changes the value of the image tag's src value by returning a random value from an array of src values (titles)

$( function(titlemagic){

```
var titles =[
```

//ive omitted the actual array contents in consideration of post length

```
            ];
```

var rand = Math.ceil(100*Math.random())

$('#id').attr('src', function(){ return titles[(rand)] }).scroll();

});

Comment: It's not that I thought that would work, that's simply as  far as I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var rand = Math.ceil(100*Math.random())
  $('#id').attr('src', function(){ return titles[(rand)] }).scroll();
});
```